# Cannot deploy django with apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, debian

I'm trying to deploy django with apache and wsgi on a debian server but I still get one error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'sinalite_app.settings' (Is it on sys.path...
```

I configured all by the book and this error is still giving me headaches.
I've added the app with command a2ensite sinalite_app

The path of the project is (where it resides manage.py) is:

```
/home/brockroot2/spider/sinalite
```

settings.py path:

```
/home/brockroot2/spider/sinalite/sinalite_app
```

wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
sys.path.append('/home/brockroot2/spider/sinalite')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sinalite_app.settings")
application = WSGIHandler()


apache file conf:

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@printeriscoming.com
    ServerName printeriscoming.com
    ServerAlias www.printeriscoming.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/printeriscoming.com/index.wsgi

    Alias /static/ /var/www/printeriscoming.com/static/
    <Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Very likely a permissions error, since the user Apache is running as is unlikely to have access to your home directory.

Comment: I've added permissions sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/. When I removed them the error file from apache was telling me there is no allowance for it. Maybe I'm not giving correct permissions, or?

Comment: Check the WSGIScriptAlias Path in the Apache config file. 
I think it should be pointing to /home/brockroot2/spider/sinalite/sinalite_app.wsgi.py. 

Also  is your project running fine with python manage.py runserver ?

Comment: Please check once for `settings.py` file inside your **sinalite_app** folder. Otherwise you will need to look for the parent folder of `setttings.py` file and set the proper one.

I think, it should be `sinalite.settings` in place of `sinalite_app.settings`. Once check it. Let me know your response. If it will not work, I will help you. You just need to paste the directory structure of your app (use **tree** command for that).